# select multiple rows from mysql and sent to jquery post function in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, .post

In my application I have to load data based on category. What I am doing is when click on the category, click function is called where I take category id and is passed to `$.post` method to a php page `load_project.php`. I that page I select the projects based on the category id and I have to sent back the selected rows to success function. My problem is when I sent the data back In my array I'll get only the last row on alert of data. I dont know where I am going. Can anyone please help me.

Php page:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#categorylink").click(function() {
            cid = $(this).attr("data-cid");
            $.post('load_project.php', { cid: "" + cid + "" }, function(data) {
                alert(data); //here I get only one row, but there is actually 3 rows
            });

        });
    });
</script>

<ul>
    <a><li data-filter="all">>All</li></a>
    <?php $get=$config->get_cat();
        while($row = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
        <a id="categorylink" data-cid="<?php echo $row['category_id'];?>">
            <li>
                <?php echo $row['category_name'];?>
            </li> 
        </a>  //this is my categories
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

load_project.php

```
<?php

    require_once 'config.php';
    $config = new DBConfig;

    if(isset($_POST['cid'])) 
    {
        $cid=$_POST['cid'];


        $get=$config->getprojectbycategory($cid);

        while($row=$get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $results['projects'] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($results);
    }
?>
```

From the success function I have to populate the rows to a grid. I am unable to do this. So currently I am passing the category id to the php page itself through href and populating the data after a page reload. Since its not that good way to load the data, I want to replace it by jquery ajax. Please help me.

***Edit 1***

When I try like this:

```
$results[] .= $row['project_name'];
```

I am getting the three project names in alert: `[[],"Private Palace","Private Villa F","23rd Floor Addax Tower"]`

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because the values you are storing in array get overwrites with previous values.

Solution for this is declare `$results['projects'] = array();` before while loop.

```
    $results['projects'] = array();
    while($row=$get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $results['projects'] = $row['project_name'];
    }
```

Comment: I declared it. But its still the same.

Comment: Can you check your query? How many records are available for `cid`.

Comment: 3 rows are available. The query is returning correct.

Comment: Check the edited answer.  I have changed this line `$results['projects'] = $row['project_name'];`. I think this will work now.

Comment: that is working, But the thing is that I need not only the project_name but also the other coloumns.